# Await on event handler

Tags: c#, .net, events, async-await

So here's deleagte and event

```
public delegate Task SomeEventHandler(SomeEventArgs e);

...


public event SomeEventHandler OnSomething;
```

Subscribers (multiple)

```
some.OnSomething += DoSomething;

...

public async Task DoSomething(SomeEventArgs e) {
    await SomethingElse();
    e.A = true;
}
```

Event call

```
if (this.OnSomething != null)
    await this.OnSomething(args);

// Here args.A is false
// It should be true
```

The problem is that last part continues even when DoSomething isn't finished. What would be the problem?

Comment: I think this signature of the event delegate is not [CLS-compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.100).aspx). By their nature and by common convention, events are expected to be `void` delegates, and you should not rely upon the order in which they're fired. You might be better off with a custom class for this logic.

Comment: Agreed; this kind of event signature is not standard practice. When WinRT faced this problem, they invented deferrals; and I recommend you use a similar pattern. I have more details in my [`async` events](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) blog post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that multiple instances of `SomeEventHandler` are running hence there are multiple `Task` values being created.  The `await` call is only running on one of them hence it's somewhat up to chance as to whether or not it's the`DoSomething` method that ends up being awaited.

To fix this you will need to `await` on every `Task` value that is created

```
if (this.OnSomething != null) {
  foreach (var d in this.OnSomething.GetInvocationList().Cast<SomeEventHandler>()) {
    await d(args);
  }
]
```

Comment: This should be standard behavior. Maybe C# v.next? :D

Comment: @AleksandarToplek it goes all the way back to C# 1.0 and is really a CLR feature vs. a C# one.  It would be a major back compat break to change it at this point